# Analogue of Lie Theory/Galois theory for Recurrence Relations

Tags: group-theory, recurrence-relations, lie-groups

I know that Galois groups let us determine when polynomials are solvable by radicals, and that Lie groups can be used to solve some differential equations.  Does there exist an analogous group theory method that tells something about the solutions of recurrence relations?  I am interested in both existence/Galois type results and symmetry methods of solution.